# Why does the script in the user data argument ignore the configuration in ~/.ssh/config?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set up some spot instance launch templates on AWS. Upon boot, a set of commands have to be executed, among which a `scp` command essentially copying a file to a remote host.

To this end, I've edited the `~/.ssh/config` file and added the necessary SSH keys to setup a secure connection. This works perfectly when I test it manually on the AWS instance (e.g. `scp file_name.txt ubuntu@host:/home/ubuntu/`).

However, when I include that same SSH command in the [user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) argument (such that it will be automatically executed upon instance boot), the connection fails because the configuration in `.ssh/config` is not applied. But when I manually supply the configuration options directly in this user data command, it works.

So why does the script in the user data argument ignore the configuration in `~/.ssh/config`? How can I force the script to consult `~/.ssh/config`?

Related question: I can manually call built-in commands in the instance by simply calling the associated command name (e.g. `touch file_name.txt`). When doing this in user data, I have to explicitly specify the full path to the associated binary (e.g. `/usr/bin/touch file_name.txt`), otherwise it will complain that the command was not found. Why is this the case? Could the reason behind this be that the instance isn't properly initialized yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to debug user-data you should check the `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` file which will contain the output.

As you're dealing with SSH keys it is worth noting that the user-data command will be running as the root user so calling `~/.ssh` will be checking in `/root/.ssh`. You should make sure the SSH key is valid for the user it is running at otherwise it will be treated at insecure.

More information about [user-data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) is available in the documentation.